# how to convert image in byte and vice versa array in xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using Signature pad to capture the signature in PCL. The code returns the signature file location with the file name. But the issue is to convert the image into byte array. I have seen multiple references but not working. below is the code sample where i am getting the location of the file with file name.

```
saveImageBtn.Clicked += (sender, e) =>{
      var value = DependencyService.Get<ISign>().Sign();
      drawingImage.SavedImagePath = value; // I am getting file location here 
      Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SignatureImagePage(drawingImage.SavedImagePath));
 };
```

i want to convert the file that i am getting in `drawingImage.SavedImagePath`. How can i do this.

Used reference previously :

> [Error - Bitmap could not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947138/convert-image-into-byte-array-in-xamarin-forms) ,
>   [Not any solution in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009307/convert-image-to-bytearray-in-xamarin-forms),
>   [Not any Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499650/xamarin-convert-image-to-byte-array)

Hope someone can provide me solution for this

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes(path);

Comment: @Jason i try to use like  byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(path); but error is File does not exists in current context. I have already used using System;

Comment: using System.IO;

Comment: Can you show the value of SavedImagePath?

Comment: You can also get the stream from the SignaturePad instead of asking a file.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955621/retrieve-image-from-signaturepadview-with-mvvm-architecture

Comment: or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44648485/stream-to-bytearray-convert-signature-pad-to-image/44662876#44662876